# Why does make add rm commands I didn't specify?

Tags: assembly, makefile, nasm, gnu-make, ld

I just created a general purpose makefile to compile and link assembler files:

```
AS=nasm
ASFLAGS=-g -f elf64
LDFLAGS=-m elf_x86_64 -static
BINARIES=print_args64

all: $(BINARIES)

%: %.o
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.asm
        $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
        $(RM) $(BINARIES) $(wildcard *.o)
```

Running `make all` I would expect following:

```
nasm -g -f elf64 -o print_args64.o print_args64.asm
ld -m elf_x86_64 -static -o print_args64 print_args64.o
```

But it actually adds a `rm` command for the object in the following:

```
 rm print_args64.o
```

Where does this come from and how can I avoid it?

I can't find any documentation for this.

Greetings, bvolkmer

Comment: You're not using the makefile you've posted here.

Comment: @user657267 It is an exact copy. Why do you think this?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't try running it more than once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`make` deleted it because it was an intermediate file not because of the `clean` target you might think. See [chapter 10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html). Relevant quotes:

> The second difference is that if make does create b in order to update
>   something else, it deletes b later on after it is no longer needed.
>   Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also
>   does not exist after make. **make reports the deletion to you by
>   printing a ‘rm -f’ command showing which file it is deleting**.

and

> You can prevent automatic deletion of an intermediate file by marking
>   it as a secondary file. To do this, list it as a prerequisite of the
>   special target .SECONDARY. When a file is secondary, make will not
>   create the file merely because it does not already exist, but make
>   does not automatically delete the file. Marking a file as secondary
>   also marks it as intermediate.
>
> You can list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as ‘%.o’) as
>   a prerequisite of the special target .PRECIOUS to preserve
>   intermediate files made by implicit rules whose target patterns match
>   that file’s name

Also note that you can ask `make` for extra information about what it is doing using the `-d` switch, which prints something like:

```
Successfully remade target file `all'.
Removing intermediate files...
rm print_args64.o
```